# DDO on Linux: game opens in 800x600 resolution

Tags: linux, wine, dungeons-and-dragons-online

I've installed DDO (Dungeons & Dragons Online) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) using wine. The launcher runs fine, and the client itself runs but is stuck in 800x600 resolution. This isn't even enough room for me to click on any buttons, let alone get into the graphics options and fix the resolution.

Is there somewhere, either in wine config, in the launcher, or in UserPreferences.ini, that I can fix the screen resolution to something usable? (My monitor is 1920x1080.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `Resolution` under `[Display]` in UserPreferences.ini. I set this to my actual monitor resolution and the resolution issues are fixed.